# Get Docker application link into pm2

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, pm2

I have a problem connecting from my `twitterservice` to `rabbitmq`. When I run everything locally, it works perfectly. As soon as I use it with docker-compose, twitterservice doesn't seem to be able to connect to rabbit. Error is eventually produced:

> Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake.

The Mongo Part works btw.

I have my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
    version: '2'
services:
  twitterservice:
    build: ./workerTwitter
    links:
      - mongodb:mongolink
      - rabbitmq:rabbitlink
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/var/lib/mongo
    command: mongod
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

Which launches perfectly.

My `pm2 processes.json`:

```
    {
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "twitter-service",
            "script": "./src",
            "merge_logs": true,
            "max_restarts": 40,
            "restart_delay": 10000,
            "instances": 1,
            "max_memory_restart": "200M",
            "env": {
                "PORT": 8080,
                "NODE_ENV": "production",
                "MONGO_DB": "mongodb://mongolink:27017/",
                "RABBIT_MQ": "amqp://rabbitlink:15672/",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When my application launches it doesn't connect to Rabbit, because it seems to be missing the right link (IP). I can access the Rabbit management console and can see that there are now ques created  How can I access the generated app from within the processes.json?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the app was trying to connect to rabbit before it was properly started and also on a wrong port. Port 5672 was the right one.